# Appending a list to a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, csv

I have a (probably) very stupid question. I am trying to use numpy to make an array with the data from a csv file. I want to have each row and column in the csv file be a unique row and column in the numpy array. To do this I read the data with the CSV module and am trying to use a for loop to append this to my numpy array. I can't get it to work.
(The csv file is using strings)

```
import csv
import numpy as np

f = open('data.csv')
csv_file = csv.reader(f)

arr = np.zeros((121, 30))
rotations = 0
x = 0

for row in csv_file:
    arr[x] = row
    x += 1

f.close()
```

Above is the code that doesn't work. (Note, I have tried using various ways of initializing the model such as numpy.full and those still haven't worked)

Comment: Have you tried using [np.append](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html) ?

Comment: append the rows to a list.  That's easier and faster.  Then make the array from the list of lists.

Comment: @Theodor, don't recommend `np.append`

Comment: What error do you get?  **doesn't work** is an inadequate way of way of describing the problem.

Comment: What error do you get?  **doesn't work** is an inadequate way of way of describing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `np.append`:

```
import csv
import numpy as np

f = open('data.csv')
csv_file = csv.reader(f)

arr = np.zeros((121, 30))
rotations = 0
x = 0

for row in csv_file:
   arr = np.append(arr,row)


f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you already know how many rows and columns to expect, so you just need to slice the contents of the row into the array.

And let's spice up your code by using a context manager and `enumerate()`!

```
with open('data.csv', 'r') as f:
    csv_file = csv.reader(f)

    for i, row in enumerate(csv_file):
        arr[i,:] = row[:]
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as each row of your csv file has 30 elements (which is what you specified as the dimension of your NumPy array), your code should work, even if the rows have values as strings. On the other hand, you can read csv data much simpler by using Pandas, which uses NumPy arrays in the background. For example,

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
arr = df.to_numpy() # This turns a Pandas dataframe to a NumPy array.
```